# Trouble understanding the poll function

Tags: python

I assume this code defines "i" as the selected objects while the selected objects X location is set to the value from the active object. Right?

```
def LocX(context):
    for i in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        i.location.x = bpy.context.active_object.location.x
```

Then there is the following code with the poll function and then the LocX command is being executed. Does this mean it will check each non active object and execute the LocX command onto it? As far as I understand the return {'FINISHED'} is a statement to say that an evaluation is done.

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return context.active_object != None

def execute(self, context):
    LocX(context)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: At this point you will benefit a lot more from learning Python beyond the context of Blender - even if your sole goal is to be able to make an add-on. http://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can think of the `poll` function as the *bouncer* that determines if the operator should be allowed to go on and process something. The return value of the poll function determines if the `execute` function is called.

The `poll` in this case checks if the scene has an `active_object`, if it does then `context.active_object` will evaluate to True, and therefore be `not None` or (different syntax same meaning) `!= None`.

The `LocX` function here doesn't even use the context parameter that was passed. The same could have been written this way:

```
def LocX():
    for i in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        i.location.x = bpy.context.active_object.location.x

....

@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return context.active_object != None

def execute(self, context):
    LocX()
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

or this way

```
def LocX(context):
    for i in context.selected_objects:
        i.location.x = context.active_object.location.x

....

@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return context.active_object != None

def execute(self, context):
    LocX(context)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

The for-loop in `LocX` loops over the collection of `selected_objects` and for each object therein sets its `location.x` to be the same as `active_object.location.x`.

---

**An aside**

As a convention we tend to use `o` or `ob` or `obj` for temporary references to objects. `i` is usually (again this is a convention) used for numbers, integers, indices.